# JSselect keys with variable of array

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array:

```
var array = [
  {
   key1: {
     underkey1: {
       "somekey":"someValue"
     }
   },
  }
];
```

I know I can reach for `key1` like this:

```
var theVar = "key1";
array[theVar];
```

But I want to reach `underkey1` with one variable, like:

```
var theVar = "key1.underkey1";
```

From what I have tried I get `undefined`.

How can it be done?

Comment: you can declatre variable as var theVar=array.key1.underkey1; and now use that variable as theVar.someValue

Comment: Can you reach key1 like you say? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split that string into array of keys and then use `reduce()` to reach nested value.

```js
var array = [{key1: {underkey1: "somevalue"},}];

var val = 'key1.underkey1'
  .split('.')
  .reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
    return r[e] || (arr[i+1] ? {} : undefined)
  }, array[0])
  
console.log(val)
```

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, you can even pass index of object in array in string like so https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2563/

Answer (score -1):

try following:

```
var array = [
    {
        key1: {
            underkey1: "somevalue"
        },
    }
];

var theVar = "key1";
theVar2 = "underkey1"
array[0][theVar][theVar2];
```

Comment: The OP said they had `var theVar = "key1.underkey1";`, this ignores that.